# Namecheap Domain not working on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting, amazon-route53, namecheap

I am new to AWS and facing this issue for the past few days. So any help will be appreciated :)

I have created an AWS EC2 instance and deployed backend&frontend services on **SINGLE INSTANCE** that are used in my project.

Backend->Java,Apache tomcat,RDS,Elasti cache

Frontend-> Node

And now created a hosted zone under Route53 to host my Namecheap domain in AWS EC2.
Have checked all configs thrice, and added ***A type(Value as ec2 IP)*** and **CNAME(Value as domain name e.g. xxyyzz.liv)** type variables in the hosted zone including modifying nameservers from hosted zone to the Namecheap DNS settings.

Even after long waiting(of 48 hrs) my domain is not getting live, tried multiple times but no help.

Comment: Can you see your configuration when running DIG: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/? Have you updated the name servers in namecheap to be that on the Route 53 public hosted zone?

Comment: Hey Chris,
I was not aware of DIG stuff, but tested now and it is displaying results with all stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be caused by misconfiguration. Perform the following steps to rectify this issue:

Ensure you **have not replaced** the `NS` or `SOA` records in Route 53, these should stay as the values that Route 53 generates. If you have replaced their values, create a new public hosted zone and migrate the records to this (excluding `NS` or `SOA`).

Run DIG against your domain for the MX record, either by running `DIG NS example.com` or by using an online tool such as https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/. If you get no results back (returning a `SERVFAIL`) or incorrect name servers back then you will need to update the name server configuration.

Within your public hosted zone in Route 53 look for the `NS` record, copy the values (there will be 4 nameservers). Then within namecheap follow [these instructions](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/767/10/how-to-change-dns-for-a-domain) for "Custom DNS". Add each name server from Route 53.

By now running DIG again you should be able to see the records that should have previously been accessible. Depending on the TTL of the previous `NS` record you might find it takes a few hours/days for the DNS to migrate across, although you can clear the DNS cache on your local network.

Comment: Thanks alot chris with the help of this debugging tool , issue got rectified and it worked by changing the port .
I was using port 3000 for frontend and 8080 for backend communication, but port 80 i.e. default for frontend make it worked :)

Comment: Great, glad I could help you :)